# Dynamic Routing in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Recently I attend on interview, he was asking about dynamic routing in mvc.

Question was how to dynamically route certain action method depending upon the parameter string or int.

for example :

```
Public ActionResult Add(datatype variable)
{  
    //depending upon the Value he was asking how to redirect.
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Redirects aren't handled by Routing, it's handled by the Actions that are executed.

I suppose what he meant was how do you create Routing rules to execute Action `Foo` if the data type is a `string`, and how do you execute action `Bar` if the data type is an `int`.

You use `Routing Constraints`, below I've added a screenshot of all supported constraints.

This is how you would use them

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    // foobar.com/home/123
    [Route("home/{id:int}")]
    public ActionResult Foo(int id)
    {
        return this.View();
    }

    // foobar.com/home/onetwothree
    [Route("home/{id:alpha}")]
    public ActionResult Bar(string id)
    {
        return this.View();
    }
}
```

More information can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx).

[image: List of supported routing constraints]